# Taurus/JMeter - Not able to achieve required throughput

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, taurus

I read this post [Taurus - API Load Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568852/taurus-api-load-testing/76946238). With regards to the provided answer, I had the following question:

For the test I have been running, we have determined it is point (2). Specifically the machine not being able to send the requests fast enough. The machine has been allocated 16GB memory and 10 core CPUs. I have run various tests with different number of users 1/10/20/50/100/200/400/800. But a certain number of threads, the hits/s doesn't go above 200 hits/s, i.e. it didn't matter if the threads were doubled, the hits/s would remain the same. And the resources were not reaching the amount allocated.

This is the code from the yaml file where the provided resources have been allocated for this test execution:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    path: ${JMETER_BIN_PATH}/jmeter
    properties:
      basedir: ${JMETER_HOME}
      output: ${TAURUS_ARTIFACTS_DIR}/output/
  memory-xmx: 15G
  cpu: 8
  detect plugins: true
```

What did work was running two instances of the Taurus test concurrently on the same machine. This showed that it wasn't the server providing the responses as causing the issue. It was able to cope with more than 400 hit/s (the total from the two tests). However, if the test were to run in a distributed mode, there are 5 scripts in total, 3 of which represent the following throughput requirements:

script 1: 100 hits/s
script 2: 200 hits/s
script 3: 300 hits/s

I can create two separate JMX files for script 1 & 2. However, what can I do about script 3? The scripts are using Concurrency Thread Group with a Throughput Shaping Timer. I'm wondering how this will work when it comes to reporting and ensuring the throughput has been achieved. There is also a requirement to run a stress test of the API server, which will be targeting over 300 hits/s.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that Taurus is a problem (i.e. the issue is not reproducible when you run JMeter without Taurus), i.e. it slows down JMeter by consuming resources to provide [real-time charts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConsoleReporter/) you can try disabling the console reported and see if it helps.

Also you can perform tuning of your JMeter instance like it's described in [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article and point Taurus to use this "tuned" JMeter instead of downloading fresh version by setting `modules.jmeter.path` property.

And last but not the least, you can reach 200 hits/s with 800 users only if response time is 4 seconds or less, check if this is the case.